# Remote Server Error - pops only few times and not always

Tags: vb.net, iis

I have a windows form that has an export button in it which exports the data on the 
form into excel,it works fine but at times it gives me this below error, 
what could be the possible reason,can anyone please let me know where I should look into?Message=The remote server returned an error: (404).

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you're calling some sort of web service.  Where's the code for that?  Do you have access to the code for it?  Are you calling the correct address for the service?  You need to add more information to your post if you want any sort of reasonably decent answer.

Comment: Hello Tim, the application makes a call to the web service and the address is right. this same button would save it some times and only few times it fails and throw this error, if at all the address of the service is set wrong it would not have saved the file correctly.

Comment: If it works some times an fails a few times, then you need to look at the service code (or talk to the service owner) and check the logs on the server.